# Prove $(a+\frac{bc}{a})(b+\frac{ca}{b})(c+\frac{ab}{c})\geq 4 \sqrt[3]{(a^3+b^3)(b^3+c^3)(c^3+a^3)}.$

Tags: inequality, summation, radicals

Given $a,b,c>0$, prove that $$(a+\frac{bc}{a})(b+\frac{ca}{b})(c+\frac{ab}{c})\geq 4 \sqrt[3]{(a^3+b^3)(b^3+c^3)(c^3+a^3)}.$$

I noticed that by AM-GM the LHS $\leq 4[\frac{2(a^3+b^3+c^3)}{3}]^3 =\frac{8}{3}(a^3+b^3+c^3)$ and the RHS $=2abc+\frac{a^2b^2}{c}+\frac{b^2c^2}{a}+\frac{c^2a^2}{b}+a^3+b^3+c^3.$ Therefore proving $2abc+\frac{a^2b^2}{c}+\frac{b^2c^2}{a}+\frac{c^2a^2}{b}\geq \frac{5}{3}(a^3+b^3+c^3)$ would suffice. However, I've found a counterexample to that last inequality. So how could I've done better?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos He says "He found a counterexample to that last inequality" (I think $a,b,c=1,1,2$ works), so I assume he might also want to know where he got it wrong?

Comment: @GarethMa  That question is quite useless in my opinion.  The OP applies AM-GM correctly (except one possible typo, but it doesn't impact the rest of the attempt), but not all attempts lead to a solution.

Comment: Okay I am sorry, I thought he might have done some mistakes in his steps, I do not know the AM-GM inequality (well enough anyways). Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

Because by AM-GM
$$\prod_{cyc}\left(a+\frac{bc}{a}\right)=\frac{1}{abc}\sqrt{\prod_{cyc}(a^2+bc)(b^2+ac)}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{abc}\sqrt{\prod_{cyc}(c(a^3+b^3)+ab(c^2+ab))}\geq\frac{1}{abc}\sqrt{\prod_{cyc}2\sqrt{c(a^3+b^3)(c^2+ab)}}.$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: Is there really a need to answer this thread rather than letting it be closed, since it is a duplicate of another thread, where you answered with the same solution?

Comment: @WE Tutorial School I did not see it. Thank you! By the way, I solved it as a new problem for me! :)